# Can a software emulation infringe a patent beginning "..a device to..", itself with existing sold hardware?

Tags: patent-infringement, software, hardware-patents

Recently, I decided to research a method of consolidating an expertise and researched any pre-existing tools which might already encapsulate my process or aid (be it software or hardware).

I came across a pre-existing hardware device, able to convey the process I was envisaging, it is available for purchase but at a *not* inconsequential price, possibly hindering access to its definite utility.

If the first line(s) of patents, for currently sold, physical hardware,  *begins* with a phrase explicitly including "...a device to...", **would my programming of a purely software-based [mobile] emulation app, containing an interface analogous, but not identical, to the real world device, infringe on that, original, hardware device?**

Comment: When you say “first line” do you mean of a claim?

Comment: What is relevant is not the first line of the whole document but of each of the claims. They are relatively short numbered sections at the end of the document and are introduced with the word “claim”. The patent as a whole might be about a device yet have one or more  method claims that a pure software product could infringe.

Comment: As suggested, there is an existing, patented, physical device, being sold. It has 2 patents, each of which, more or less start with "...a device to/which...", within the first 10 words, first paragraph of each patent. Are such patents enforceable against a piece of software that emulates the hardware 'device' - think rubber-keyed, injection moulded, calculator versus the calculator on your mobile phone? Up to this point, **I have released NO software to date to itself be contested**, I am simply 'feeling around'.

Comment: The first lines of the document are not what would determine the answer. It is the first words of each claim. They are numbered and at the end of the patent.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, thank you. I will read into those claims, I simply wondered if this 'device' moniker meant something akin to 'as built within a physical apparatus'. Again, I will now investigate this claims more thoroughly, as I very much hope to be able to code something offering similar functionality, but as a reasonably priced mobile app.

Comment: The word device does mean something relevant if it is the preamble to a claim.

Comment: Please simply link to the 2 patents you are interested in. That way we can actually help you.

Comment: @EricS, I thank you, I would be very glad of help, however, if I were to post those patents on here, I worry that I am also 'alerting' others to my software idea plus explicitly 'outing' myself in any potential challenge. I'm between a rock and a hard place. I've more or less decided to go ahead with my idea but to attempt to make the interface/layout of my software product as far removed from the physical interface of the 3rd party sold hardware device, while rendering similar utility to the end user. Again, I thank you for you concern.

Comment: Then the only advice I can provide is to consult with an actual patent attorney. In the meantime, just focus on the claims. If you are unsure what a claim means you could post a question about it where you edit out the technical bits to anonymize things.

Comment: @EricS, again, thank you. I may consider posting the claims. I had a look, the first 3 or 4 claims suggested hardware (cpu), around the 8th claim, software/algorithms were suggested, including example source code. 

This might sound pig-headed but, I'm going to write my application, anyway, as an exercise and consolidation of my considered problem domain (I am NOT an expert). In itself, it will be a learning experience. The process will *not* be a waste of time, even if my app is later deemed to infringe and eventually shut-down (assuming a 'cease and desist' might one-day materialise).

Comment: @BigRich That is fine. Claims are legal writing so parsing them can be hard for inventors. Remember, to infringe on a claim you have to implement every element in the claim. If there are 5 elements and you only do 4 of them you don’t infringe.

Comment: @BigRich - to avoid claims the claims need to be studied and designed around. As Eric says if you can leave out a claimed element you don't infringe. Changing the user interface if the user interface details are not claimed (very very unlikely that they are) will make your product different in a way that is not at all related to any potential infringement. Separately, it would be very odd to include sample code in a claim so I'm not sure you are looking at it entirely correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are only a few statutory categories that any claim in a U.S. patent must fall into - "process, machine, manufacture, or composition of matter". An apparatus, device or system would be a machine or possibly a manufacture (meaning something that was manufactured). A method would be a process. Methods are defined in terms of steps, while machines etc. are defined in terms of structure or in terms of functions inherent do to the structure.

A program would not directly infringe a claim that starts "A device . . . ". But the same patent may have method claims. To make this more complicated, a system (a machine) can be defined in terms of what it does when you turn it on (a process) so wording in the claim include steps but the claim is not to a method but a machine that carries out the steps. Your initial thought to look at the preamble is key to this.

If your software works by being installed on a phone then your software is not a "device" but the phone + software is a device. You are not directly infringing a device claim or system claim in that case if you just provide the software.

But there are also a few forms of *in*direct infringement that you may be guilty of practicing even if you do not make or sell an actual claimed device. This includes induced infringement and contributory infringement.

Comment: I will look more carefully into what induced infringement and contributory infringement are, I thank you.